# RISC-V infinite loop with large array size

Tags: c, riscv, bare-metal

**Questions**

I'm running a program with RISC-V vector intrinsic functions on simulator.
It's a bare-metal program built on SiFive's freedom-e-sdk.

When I set the array size >= 4096 with float type, the program will enter an infinite loop.

It works well for array size <= 4000. It also works well for `float16` with array size = 4096.

I would like to ask for the real cause of such limitation.

```
float input[4096];
for (int i=0; i<4096; i++) {
    input[i] = i;
}

size_t vl;
float* src = input;
vfloat32m8_t result;

for (int i=4096; i>0; i-=vl) {
    vl = vsetvl_e32m8(i);
    vfloat32m8_t operand = vle32_v_f32m8(src, vl);
    result = vfmul_vv_f32m8(operand, operand, vl);
    src += vl;
}
```

**Solution**

As suggestions in the comments, this is a memory issue.
The stack size allocated for this program is not large enough to accommodate the input array.
After enlarging the stack size in linker script, this program can work well.

Comment: that's a huge 16K array. How much memory do you have on that board?

Comment: The program was ran on a systemc simulator. The maximum memory size is 512KiB. And maximum stack size is 32KiB.

Comment: Have you checked stack overflow? verify stack pointer. Try allocating memory on heap.

Comment: Looks like a memory mapping issue, seen this many times :)